Football pools in Dr Who
I was just online buying my National Lottery tickets and I got to thinking about Dr Who.
In School Reunion he meets Sarah Jane Smith after many years, prior to this it's disclosed that he got the teaching role because the previous teacher won the National Lottery with a mystery ticket posted through his door.
When Donna Noble was at the wedding a mystery benefactor sends a winning lottery ticket.
Both occasions are clearly the work of the Doctor.
However, many years ago (possibly the Peter Davison timelord but not 100% certain) I saw a Doctor giving someone the winning numbers for the football pools, does anyone know which episode?

The Tardis Wiki is pretty extensive, and list no mentions in any TV episodes: https://tardis.wiki/wiki/Football_pools

Not to mention how almost all of Kazran Sardick's employees all quit on him because they ALL won he lottery. Their planet did not have a lottery.

Chakoteya has a pretty solid transcript of the Doctor Who series; I can't see any relevant mention of the "football pools" "the pools" or even "pools"; https://tinyurl.com/yz54wwx8

It turns out that it wasn't Dr Who that I was trying to recall, but another story about a time traveller; "Another flip for Dominick" (sequel to "The flip side of Dominick Hyde")
In the sequel he returns from the future to visit the girl (in the 1980s) that he fell in love with....to ensure her financial security he jumps forward a few days to get the football results, then travels back and gets her to fill in the football pools coupon.
Sorry for the red herring, I really thought it was The Doctor who did it.

The Doctor has too much respect for the game to mess with the pools like that.

Just a quick reminder that you can accept your own answer.
